# PHP script works fine manually but not via cronJob

Tags: php, cron

I have the following script in php :

```
<?php 
   ini_set('log_errors', true); 
   ini_set('error_log', __DIR__ . '/cron.html'); 
   error_log("I'm working"); 
?>
```

When I execute this script manually by visiting the URL on the browser it works fine and it creates a new file "cron.html" with this content :

```
[02-Jan-2014 10:25:39 Europe/Berlin] I'm working
```

But once I try to executed it via Cron it doesn't work. And to see if I have problem with path I told the command on cron to create me a log file.

```
*/1 * * * * wget -O - -q 'http://www.mywebsite.com/cron.php' > /PATH-TO-FOLDER/crobtab.log
```

The file crobtab.log is created every single time, but the script is not working at all.

Could this be a problem with the server ? Safe Mode ? Any idea Please ?

Comment: so what log file is saying, any error ?

Comment: No the log file is empty

Comment: When you say you are executing it manually, do you mean visiting the URL in a browser or executing it on the command line?

Comment: Do you execute it manually locally?

Comment: @Jeremy, Yes I visit the url on the browser

Comment: You pass `-O`, `-`, `-q` - what is the second (empty) option for?

Comment: Then forgive my ignorance/laziness, but I just checked the crons I have setup using wget and I don't have the `- -q` in the command.  Maybe that helps?

Comment: Oh, and not sure if it matters, but I don't quote the URL in the wget command.

Comment: @Jeremy, I try it and it send me this error via mail : HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 406 Not Acceptable

Comment: @Alpha That means your webserver thinks wget won't accept what it wants to return, so you'll need to send the accept types back.  Check http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html for details.

Comment: @Jeremy, I didn't get it. Could explain more please ?

Comment: It's part of a HTTP Request -- browsers send what kind of content they accept as part of the headers.  Your server is expecting those and is throwing the error b/c it's not receiving them, so you'll have to find out what it is expecting and mimic them on the command line.

Comment: Can you access the server via SSH? In that case, you should try running the command from the command line, and try different options in wget

Comment: @Alex, No I don't have access !

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use absolute paths in crontab.

Try this

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O /PATH-TO-FOLDER/crobtab.log http://www.mywebsite.com/cron.php
```

or this

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -o /PATH-TO-FOLDER/crobtab.log http://www.mywebsite.com/cron.php
```

Comment: Use the curl option, or possibly even lynx.. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Comment: @Cardeol : I tried the second one with curl, in the output gives me this error : `406 Not Acceptable This request is not acceptable`

Comment: That is because the USER AGENT, you should be able to create a fake USER AGENT like in order to get the data. I.E. Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0